# Create Custom Magento Admin Page Layout

Tags: xml, magento, templates, layout

I'm trying to create a custom Magento admin page, but I can't seem to get my layout or template to appear within the page. The page shows up fine in the menu, but when you click it you just get a blank admin page. I've followed a few different tutorials, and have gone through the whole process at least twice, but can't figure out why my template isn't appearing. [You can download all the source here.](http://francisbaptiste.com/SaxxForzani.zip)

Answer (score 0):

In Saxx_Forzani_Block_Adminhtml_Forzani you could do

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('forzani/admincontent.phtml');
}
```

In the controller you could then do

```
public function indexAction()
{
     $this->_initAction()
        ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('saxx_forzani/adminhtml_forzani'))
        ->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: This should work as long as Saxx_Forzani_Block_Adminhtml_Forzani extends Mage_Core_Block_Template